# Using web sockets in UWP background tasks

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, uwp, background

I am trying to make a background task for a UWP app. The task should be triggered by packets from a web socket connection.

I have tested the web socket and it works as expected.

For the background task to work, according to the Microsoft tutorial on background networking ([Network communications in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background)), a `ControlChannelTrigger` must be instantiated and the [`channel.UsingTransport(socket)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.usingtransport) method must be called. Then [`socket.ConnectAsync(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamwebsocket.connectasync) should be called.

However, when calling `socket.ConnectAsync(...)` after `channel.UsingTransport(socket)`, the `socket.ConnectAsync(...)` method throws an exception with the following message.

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F75

When called without `channel.UsingTransport(socket)`, the connection is established without problems.

In order to use the socket in a background task, I must establish the connection after calling `channel.UsingTransport(socket)`.

Can anyone shed some light on why this error might be occurring?

Comment: What is your targeted platform for this app? The `ControlChannelTrigger` class is not available for windows phones.

Comment: It is Desktop x64. I am aware of the phone limitation. This app is not for phones.

Comment: One last obvious question, did you call `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()`[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundexecutionmanager.requestaccessasync)?  I understand this does not needed to be called from the UI thread, but from your posted code, there is no way to know that.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have two methods that set up background tasks. Each one called the `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()` before registering tasks. I just checked if the error was due to two calls to the method by removing the second, but the same exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't install the IIS server on the same device and use localhost to connect the server. See [network isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx) topic. When using the server in official [WebSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket) , you can try to copy the server folder and its subfolder to another computer and run the server scripts, then you can connect the server with a IP address such as:

Server uri:  ws://xxx.xx.xx.xx/WebSocketSample/echowebsocket.ashx

Besides, please have a try to test the [ControlChannelTrigger StreamWebSocket](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8) sample.

Also see the Note part in the sample:

> When used with the supplied scripts, this Windows Store app sample communicates with another process (IIS server which is a desktop app) on the same machine over loopback for demonstration purposes only. A Windows Store app that communicates over loopback to another process that represents a Windows Store app is not allowed and such apps will not pass Store validation. For more information, see [How to configure network isolation capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh770532).